# sending array to server without appending to url using post service

Tags: php, objective-c, post

Hello I am trying to send an array to server without appending it to the url, but its not happening.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setObject:@"Kiran" forKey:@"name"];
[dict setObject:@"kumar" forKey:@"lName"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.125/vblive_new/api/getMobileContactList?"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[jsonDict setValue:dict forKey:@"userName"];
NSLog(@"JSON Dict: %@",jsonDict);//Check your array here...


NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonData length]];
NSLog(@"JSON String: %@",jsonString); //Check your post String here...
NSLog(@"post length is %@",postLength);
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Data-Type"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:true];
```

Comment: Perhaps your program is finished early, than request will be send.
Try send a sync request
<pre><code>[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];</code></pre>